# Релизная версия приложения не работает

Tags: android, jackson

Использую библиотеку Jackson, в отладочном режиме все работает хорошо без каких либо ошибок, но релизная версия не работает. Сталкивался с подобной проблемой она заключалась в том, что json не всегда содержал ключи которые прописанные у меня в pojo классе решил ее установив аннотацию

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Если возможность как-то в релиз версии включить лог, что бы можно было понять, что не так? 
(В качестве геттеров сеттеров использую lambok)

Comment: Хммм... А что в релизной версии кто запрещает `Log.i()` - поставьте и покажите логи.

Comment: А куда вывести, после сборки Log.i();? android studio уже логи не покажет. Или я чего-то не понял.

Comment: Вы что-то путаете: логи выводятся в любом случае, только в релизной сборке фильтруются дебажные и маловажные. Главное чтобы на устройстве был включен режим разработчика. Предположение по проблеме: в релизе включён прогуард/R8, но не прописаны правила исключений - из-за этого json-парсер не находит нужных полей или сеттеров. Решения: 1) отключить (`minifyEnabled false`); 2) занести POJO в исключения  и, возможно, ещё классы парсера 3) задать имена json-полей аннотациями (если парсер поддерживает).

Comment: @Ильдар да, вы не поняли. 1) Надо включить режим разработчика в телефоне (зависит от модели телефона) 2) Подключить телефон шнурочком к компу и Студия как миленькая будет показывать логи (за исключением `Log.d()`)